# Detecting that log file has been deleted or truncated on POSIX systems?

Tags: c, unix, file-io, posix, truncate

Suppose a long-running process writes to a log file.  Suppose that log file is kept open indefinitely.  Suppose that a careless system administrator deletes that log file.  Can the program detect that this has happened?

Is it safe to assume that `fstat()` will report a link count of zero for a deleted file?

Truncation, it seems to me, is slightly trickier.  In part, it depends on whether the file  descriptor is running in `O_APPEND` mode.  If the log file is not running with `O_APPEND`, then the current write position of the program's log descriptor doesn't change, and the truncation removes the leading bytes, but the program continues to write at 'the end', leaving a gap of phantasmal zero bytes (they read as zeroes, but don't necessarily occupy space on disk).

If the program runs with `O_APPEND`, then it will write at the end of the file as it currently exists.  The only way to observe the truncation is to note that the file position is not where the program expected it - which in turn means tracking that position explicitly.

On the whole, I'm not so worried about truncation as deletion, but any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: How about locking instead of detecting deletion?

Comment: @snot: I don't see how that would help much.  Advisory locking would be ignored; mandatory locking is unusual - not impossible, but I'd prefer not to.  Besides, administrators should be allowed to manipulate logs within reason.  It may be that the software needs a better 'change log file' mechanism.

Comment: Filenames are just pointers to files, when nothing points to a file it is deleted.  Since you can always add a link and then delete another the link count might not help, the best you can probably do is to check if the filename still exists or if your process is the only one with a link to the file.

Comment: @Robert: not quite; the file has to be closed by all processes before it is freed.  If the daemon holds the file open, then the disk space remains allocated to the file, and the inode is not reused - even though there's no name.  You cannot relink a file with no name, at least, not in classic Unix.

Comment: Nothing you said contradicts anything I said.

Comment: @Robert: okay - then I'll label my misunderstanding of what you said as a problem imposed by 300-character limits on comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking that `fstat()` returns a link count of zero would fail if the file was hard linked or renamed.  I would probably instead periodically compare `stat()`'s inode number against `fstat()`'s.

I'm not sure about truncation.

`tail -F` checks for deletion and maybe truncation, so I'd check its source to see how it implements it.

Comment: Good point on the link count not being zero if the file was hard linked.  For my purposes, renaming is not a problem.  I'll need to think about whether linking is a problem - the data is still available via some name, which is the key thing.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the careless system administrator kills the process. Do you really want to protect against the admin doing random things? I guess you're just looking for a way to start a new logfile from time to time, like using `logrotate`. There it is enough to provide a way to manually let the program reopen the logfile. The standard way to do this is to listen for the HUP-Signal in the program, and reopen the logfile if it arrives:

```
#include <signal.h>

volatile int f_sighup;

void sighup_handler() {
  f_sighup = 1;
}

void trap_sighup() {
  struct sigaction sa;
  int rv;

  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
  sa.sa_handler = &sighup_handler;
  rv = sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
  if (-1 == rv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "warning: setting SIGHUP signal handler failed");
  }
}

int main() {
  f_sighup = 0;
  trap_sighup();
  ...
}
```

Then regularly check the `f_sighup` flag in the main program to see if the logfile should be reopened.
This plays nice with tools like `logrotate`, which can rename the old logfile and then call `kill -s HUP $PID`. And the careless sysadmin can do this manually, after deleting (or better renaming) the old logfile.

Comment: Should that be "sig_atomic_t volatile f_sighup = 0;"?

Comment: Probably can't hurt, though I would assume int to be always atomic. volatile might be a good idea in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [inotify](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify.html) to watch your log file, monitoring it for file system events.

Comment: Interesting software - but I'm looking at it from the perspective of the program writing the log file, not from the outside 'consumer' of the log file.

Comment: `inotify` can help you with either task, but it's Linux-specific.

Answer (score 1):

In response to [søren-holm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651834/s%c3%b8ren-holm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37835392)

> When a file is closed the modification time is changed.

that doesn't appear to be correct:

```
import os
from time import sleep

TMPF = '/tmp/f'

def print_stats():
    print("%s, %s" % (os.stat(TMPF).st_mtime, os.stat(TMPF).st_ctime))
    sleep(1.1)

print("Opening...")
with open(TMPF, 'w') as f:
    print_stats()
    print("Writing...")
    os.write(f.fileno(), 'apple')
    print_stats()
    print("Flushing...")
    f.flush()
    print_stats()
    print("Closing...")

print_stats()
```

Produces:

```
Opening...
1483052647.08, 1483052647.08
Writing...
1483052648.18, 1483052648.18
Flushing...
1483052648.18, 1483052648.18
Closing...
1483052648.18, 1483052648.18
```

Admittedly, there's a bit of Python magic going on in there; that `write()` is not reasonably guaranteed to be flushed automatically, but the point stands that mtime is updated when the file is modified, not when the file is closed.  The behavior of `ctime` is going to depend on your filesystem and its mount options.

Comment: Looking at the POSIX specification of [`close()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) supports the contention that `close()` doesn't affect the modification times on files.  By contrast, the POSIX specification for [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) does stipulate that the modification time is changed.  So, at least in theory, if you write to a file at say 09:00:00 and keep the file open without further modification until 15:00:00, the 'last updated time remains 09:00:00.

Answer (score -1):

When a file is closed the modification time is changed. So check periodically on the mtime using stat() will work.

Comment: Looking at the POSIX specification of [`close()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) supports the contention that `close()` doesn't affect the modification times on files.  By contrast, the POSIX specification for [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) does stipulate that the modification time is changed.  So, at least in theory, if you write to a file at say 09:00:00 and keep the file open without further modification until 15:00:00, the 'last updated time remains 09:00:00.