# Improving the performance in fopen/ fclose scenario

Tags: c, performance, c89

The following situation:
I'm editing a single method in a huge Program, which gets called very often, but I don't know how often exactly(different for each run).

Now I have to add logging to a txt file, and opening/closing the file on each call is a huge bottleneck for the whole application.

Just leaving the file open isn't realy an option, because I don't know if its the last call to this function.

Is there a way to speed this up without modifying the calling site?
I'd rather avoid changing the method signature, because that would cause problems when we combine the work with my coworkers( no working version control here)

Comment: So, don't open and close the file on each call.  The file will be flushed and closed when your program terminates normally.  You probably should use `fflush()` after each logging call (though that has some overhead).  But don't open/close each call — it is too slow.  Consider append mode — it's probably a good idea.  You don't need to change the interface to the functions; you just create a `static FILE *stdlog = 0;` variable at file scope and if the pointer is null when you log, open the file.  Thereafter, use `stdlog` as the log file stream.  If you prefer not to risk `stdlog`, try `log_fp`.

Comment: Use a buffer for logging, once the log buffer is full write it to the file.

Comment: And in the 20th Century, no working version control was a stupid mistake (offense).  In the 21st Century, it is ridiculously unprofessional.

Comment: @rakib_: stdio already has buffers. There's no reason to reimplement buffering yourself for this unless you have very specialized needs.

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Give us a broader picture.

Comment: If you are on a Unix- or Linux-based system, consider using `syslog()`.

Comment: @R..  Not sure how that helps avoiding too file much file open/close issue.

Comment: And the answer to the headline question is "No, there isn't a way to speed up `fopen()` and `fclose()`".

Comment: @rakib_: It doesn't; see my answer for an answer to OP's problem. I was just saying that your comment is not productive and not a good idea for OP to do since it introduces useless duplicate/NIH'd code.

Comment: @SteveSummit: If OP is using a Linux-based system, `open` (and thus `fopen`) is crazy fast anyway, probably on the order of 20-50 microseconds. You'd need to be doing a lot of logging for it to be a significant percentage of overall run time.

Comment: You might find [Detecting that a log file has been deleted or truncated on POSIX systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462122/detecting-that-log-file-has-been-deleted-or-truncated-on-posix-systems) useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the file open. All files are closed (which includes flushing any pending buffers) when your program calls `exit` or returns from `main`. There is no reason to care whether a call to the log function is the "last call".

Answer (score 0):

An addition to R..'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46650545/4618618), you could also catch the interrupt or terminate signal and close the file yourself.